# How to achieve encapsulation in C++ project

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, strategy-pattern

I'm currently learning about OOP design patterns and I'm working on a project whose main class is roughly organized as follows:

```
class MainClass {
  public:
     MainClass(int something, CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm algoType);
     double getResult();
     
  private:
     std::vector<double> _numbers;
     CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm _algoType;
};
```

where `CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm` is an enum. Basically, depending on the specific algorithm used, the `getResult()` function acts accordingly. So far, I've been using simple switch statements in the implementation of the latter. As this class will grow a lot when further algorithms are introduced, I want to encapsulate the algorithm in its own class somehow. I tried out implementing the Strategy Pattern but end up with the problem that the classes implementing different algorithms need to be friend classes of MainClass - as they need to access private member variables of MainClass (e.g. `_numbers`). How would I accomplish proper and clean encapsulation in this situation?

Comment: Having a single instance of `MainClass` with all of your program state isn't encapsulation. It's disguised global variables, and it's no better (and less honest) than just having global variables in the first place. Pass arguments to a function, and pass exactly what the function needs. Don't rely on everyone having access to the *same* `MainClass` instance.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I edited my question as I'm not looking to "improve" encapsulation and I know my project has nothing to do with encapsulation so far. I want to start learning about it by implementing different algorithms in an encapsulated way similar to the Strategy Pattern. My project structure is actually far more complex than the minimal example, I just wanted to give an idea about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you might be wanting a Factory.

Comment: Can you simply inherit from `MainClass` and instead of clients passing an enum, let them just create correct object? Basically the strategy pattern, but with `MainClass` as the abstract strategy. If not, what's wrong with just passing arguments to the separate strategy, as they need it?

Comment: Or just let it take a functional object that takes a `std::vector<double>&` and returns a `double`, [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ed5MsYKe7).

Comment: Do all the algorithms operate on the same data and variables?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen andbitmask: That's quite an idea, iit wouldn't make much sense semantically though, I'm looking more for like an abstract class and derived classes for different algorithm implementations as Galik suggested. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: @Galik yes, they all operate on the same data, they need modify MainClass private members though

Comment: I agree with @TedLyngmo: I'm thinking you want to use `std::function<double(std::vector<double>&)>` in place of the enum. That lets you abstract the details of that function from the API of our class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach would be to make `Algorithm` a pure virtual (*interface*) class with various implementations (like `AlgorithmSimpleSum` below), a bit like this:

```
// Pure Virtual Interface
class Algorithm
{
public:
    virtual ~Algorithm() = default;

    virtual double process(double const* begin, double const* end) const = 0;
};

class MainClass {
  public:
     MainClass(std::vector<double> const& numbers, std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> algorithm)
     : numbers(numbers), algorithm(std::move(algorithm)) {}

     double getResult() { return algorithm->process(numbers.data(), numbers.data() + numbers.size()); }

  private:
     std::vector<double> numbers;
     std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> algorithm;
};

// Concrete implementation of an Algorithm
class AlgorithmSimpleSum
: public Algorithm
{
public:

    double process(double const* begin, double const* end) const override
    {
        double r = 0.0;

        while(begin != end)
            r += *begin++;

        return r;
    }
};
```

You can make the parameter to the `Algorithm::process()` function a `std::vector<double> const&`, but that is a bit less generic/flexible, although it has the advantage of being simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is actually what I've been trying but my algorithm implementations need to modify `std::vector<double> numbers` and/or access private implementations of MainClass to function.

Comment: @Brosch Then you could simply modify the parameters of `Algorithm::process()` accordingly. For example, you could pass in non-const references to the variables that need modifying by the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` inheritance and members would be one option:

```
class MainClass {
  public:
     MainClass(int something, CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm algoType);
     double getResult();
     
  protected:
     std::vector<double> _numbers;
     CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm _algoType;
};

class Algorithm1 : protected MainClass {
  public:
    using MainClass::MainClass;
    // option 1
    using MainClass::getResult();
    // option 2
    double getResult() { return 42; }
};

template <CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm AType>
auto factory(int something) {
  if constexpr (AType == CrazyTypeOfAlgorithm::A1) return Algorithm1(something, AType);
  // more cases ...
}
```